# How to send multiple checkbox values through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Hi I have multiple banks which user can select one or multiple.I am sending data through ajax but the problem is I get the first bank selected when I dd my request,I want the value of every bank which has been selected by the user.
below is my code.I have different other components as well.

bankSelector.blade

```
                    <input
                        id="bank_{{$item['code']}}"
                        name="banks"
                        class="form-check-input bank"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value="{{$item['code']}}"
                        checked/>
```

ajax.js

```
              $('form').submit(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              let formData = new FormData(this)
            
        $.ajax({
          url: "/product/save",
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="_token"]').attr("content"),
          },
          success: function (data) {

            // show("#step8");
          },
          error: function () {

        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array for name of checkboxes `name="banks[]"`

```
<input
                        id="bank_{{$item['code']}}"
                        name="banks[]"
                        class="form-check-input bank"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value="{{$item['code']}}"
                        checked/>
```